# Programmatically select the first suggestion in django-autocomplete-light

Tags: javascript, python, django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

How can I select the first given option? I'm feeding the autocomplete widget with the data from reverse geocoding results (city) basing on user's location. I have a database with cities and I need to select the first suggested option.

**autocomplete_light_registry.py**

```
autocomplete_light.register(
    City,
    search_fields=('^name',),
    autocomplete_js_attributes={'placeholder': _('Start typing...')}
)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(City.objects.all(), label=_('City'), widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('CityAutocomplete'))
```

**locations.js**

```
$('#id_city_text').val(ymaps.geolocation.city);
var autocomplete = $('#id_city_text').yourlabsAutocomplete();
autocomplete.refresh();
```

Thanks for your help.

Screenshots:

- http://cl.ly/image/2V0I373e2C0M (achieved)
- http://cl.ly/image/3S2p382o2N12 (goal)

References:

- https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light
- http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something in the Cyrillic, but aren't both of the posted screenshots the same?

Comment: @summea Thanks for catching, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to auto select the first choice if there is only one:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var autocomplete = $('#id_city_text').yourlabsAutocomplete();
            autocomplete.show = function(html) {
                yourlabs.Autocomplete.prototype.show.call(this, html)
                var choices = this.box.find(this.choiceSelector);

                if (choices.length == 1) {
                    this.input.trigger('selectChoice', [choices, this]);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: how to do this version 3.x ?

Comment: v3 uses select2, not jquery-auocomplete-light, for v3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395427/programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-select2-ajax

Answer (score 4):

You have to select the choice programmatically too:

```
$('#id_city_text').val(ymaps.geolocation.city);
var autocomplete = $('#id_city_text').yourlabsAutocomplete();
autocomplete.show('<span class="div" data-value="'+ymaps.geolocation.cityId+'">'+ymaps.geolocation.city+'</span>');
$('#id_city_text').trigger('selectChoice', [autocomplete.box.find(':first-child'), autocomplete]);
```

The idea is to trigger 'selectChoice' on a first auto-complete suggestion.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. It does not select the 1st suggested element

Comment: @DmitryDemidenko But data-value must be the ID for stored City and not a string :)

Comment: The real output is `<span data-value="2453" class="div">Санкт-Петербург</span>`

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/139#issuecomment-18332107

**locations.js**

```
$('#id_city_text').val(ymaps.geolocation.city);
var autocomplete = $('#id_city_text').yourlabsAutocomplete();
autocomplete.refresh();
autocomplete.show = function(html) {
    yourlabs.Autocomplete.prototype.show.call(this, html)
    var choices = this.box.find(this.choiceSelector);

    if (choices.length == 1) {
        this.input.trigger('selectChoice', [choices, this]);
    }
}
```